# sys.spt_check_constbytable_rowset in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've a list of long running queries on production servers(MS SQL Server 2005) and the most time consuming query is something like this - 

`SELECT TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA ...
FROM sys.spt_check_constbytable_rowset`

I've been trying to find any object named `sys.spt_check_constbytable_rowset` in all DBs (including sys DBs) but no luck.

Could anyone please provide some information about this `sys.spt_check_constbytable_rowset`

This list is provided by the client, so i'm not sure how they've got it- DB trace or something else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: also when i try to google it, the only thing i find is http://www.g-productions.nl/index.php?name=spt_check_constbytable_rowset&version=2005RTM which does not provides any information about it whatsoever

Comment: answer the question or up-vote it :D

Comment: Looks like it gets called by the stored procedure `sp_check_constbytable_rowset`. You can only select from that view directly (`select * from sys.spt_check_constbytable_rowset`) via the DAC.

Comment: And also the definition of that view looks pretty innocuous and unlikely to be long running unless they are in the habit of leaving long running uncommitted DDL transactions open.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on my production server.

By looking deeper into it, I found that this type of queries comes from the SSIS package validation process where it is actually validation the objects and other schema information, some time it also executes from different server through linked server.

Thanks